# PHP - count number of arrays within an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using the following foreach to get the locationName for each site but I am having trouble counting the number of dataTypes for each location.

```
$stuff = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($stuff['sites'] as $chunk) {
  $locationName = $chunk['locationName'];

  foreach($chunk["dataTypes"] as $action) {

    // print_r($action);
    print_r(array_count_values($action);

    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple as the var_dump gives me those numbers but I can't work it out at all.

eg.

Test 1 - book 0, tape 0, records 0, virtual 1

Test 2 - book 2, tape 1, records 0, virtual 1

Here's the data.

```
var_dump($stuff);

array(2) { 
    ["userId"]=> string(3) "618" 
    ["sites"]=> array(2) { 
        ["locationId"]=> string(4) "0002" 
        ["locationName"]=> string(6) "Test 1" 
        ["dataType"]=> array(4) { 
            ["book"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["tape"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["records"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["virtual"]=> array(1) { 
                [0]=> array(2) { 
                    ["dataId"]=> string(3) "200" 
                    ["information"]=> string(6) "info 2" 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        ["locationId"]=> string(4) "0003" 
        ["locationName"]=> string(6) "Test 2" 
        ["dataType"]=> array(4) { 
            ["book"]=> array(2) { 
                [0]=> array(2) { 
                    ["dataId"]=> string(2) "12" 
                    ["information"]=> string(11) "information" 
                    } 
                [1]=> array(2) { 
                    ["dataId"]=> string(2) "11" 
                    ["information"]=> string(4) "info" 
                    } 
                } 
            ["tape"]=> array(1) { 
                [0]=> array(2) { 
                    ["dataId"]=> string(4) "1121" 
                    ["information"]=> string(4) "info" 
                    } 
                } 
            ["records"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["virtual"]=> array(1) { 
                [0]=> array(2) { 
                    ["dataId"]=> string(1) "1" 
                    ["information"]=> string(4) "none" 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
```

Thank you for any pointers, examples or tutorials you can direct me to.

Comment: `dataTypes` !== `dataType` ( + missing `)` )

Comment: I'm not sure where I'm meant to use that?

Comment: Look at your second foreach loop and your array

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand.

Comment: You are trying to access an index called: *dataType **s***, but in your array you only have *dataType* . + `print_r(array_count_values($action);` <- Missing bracket here